# Plupload Filebrowser does not open

Tags: silverlight, flash, asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload, plupload

I'm trying to use plupload with mvc2 but the filebrowser-window does not open.

my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

// Convert divs to queue widgets when the DOM is ready
$(function () {
    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html5',
        url: '<%: Url.Content( "~//Uploades/Horses/" ) %>',
        max_file_size: '10mb',
        chunk_size: '1mb',
        unique_names: true,

        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90 },

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters: [
        { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
        { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
    ],

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: '../../../../Scripts/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: '../../../../Scripts/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap'
    });

    // Client side form validation
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();
        uploader.refresh();
        // Validate number of uploaded files
        if (uploader.total.uploaded == 0) {
            // Files in queue upload them first
            if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
                // When all files are uploaded submit form
                uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function () {
                    if (uploader.total.uploaded == uploader.files.length)
                        $('form').submit();
                });

                uploader.start();
            } else
                alert('You must at least upload one file.');

            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```
<div id="uploader" style="height:300px">
        <p>You browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight, Gears, BrowserPlus or HTML5 support.</p>
    </div>
```

If I try to debug the uploadingelemt is showen with out any problems. But If I click add files the window just jumps to the top of my page and nothin else happens.

Firebug does not show any problems.

I've tried in FF4 & IE 8 using flash and silverlight

Any one an idea?
Thank you very much and wish you a nice weekend!

Comment: I get the same thing, haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Do the same thing you did for url: '<%: Url.Content( "~//Uploades/Horses/" ) %>' on the flash_swf_url: properties as well. May not fix the issue but it ensures your paths are correct. The biggest issue I have come across are the paths being broken.

Comment: have you added all relevant js dependencies? have you tried with a specific runtime i.e. just html5 or html 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser will use Flash runtime as it is listed before the 'html5'. Flash runtime requires setting of 'container: "my_uploader_container_id"'

And your 'pickfiles' button need to be placed into the DIV with ID 'my_uploader_container_id'.

Another solution is using html5 engine - list it before flash in 'runtimes' parameter. But html5 runtime does not work in IE.

Comment: This worked for me also. It's not clear from the documentation - but this works. :)